# segmentation fault for gcloud CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gcloud-cli

I am using gcloud-cli. installed it on ubuntu 18.04 using snap.

verified logs, even ran in verbose mode. But could not find any reason for segmntation fault.

Command I am using

`gcloud init --verbosity=debug`

Issue I am facing

```
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.init] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
Welcome! This command will take you through the configuration of gcloud.

Your current configuration has been set to: [default]

You can skip diagnostics next time by using the following flag:
  gcloud init --skip-diagnostics

Network diagnostic detects and fixes local network connection issues.
Checking network connection...Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any Help appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the snap and install package [`google-cloud-sdk`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#deb) or as [standalone](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/#linux).